# Why are my contextmenu entries lower case?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-explorer, file-association

I'm using `BrendanGrant.Helpers.FileAssociation;` (a NuGet package) to create file-associations for my application. It works fine so far. However, I have a problem with the `ProgramVerb`s:

When I create a ProgramAssociation and add verbs to it like this:

```
  var pai = new ProgramAssociationInfo(fai.ProgID);

  pai.Create(
    "App name",
    new[]
    {
      new ProgramVerb("Öffnen", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + " \"%1\""),
      new ProgramVerb("Bearbeiten", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + " \"%1\"")
    });
}
```

The Bearbeiten and Öffnen (edit and open) keywords are lowercase in the contextmenu of windows explorer:

[image]

I named the 2nd entry WAAAA to test if its something only changing the first character, but apparently its not.

What do I have to change, so that my Bearbeiten and Öffnen is uppercase in the context menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked this library and it seems that you have no influence on this behavior.

This is the line that changes to lowercase:

```
RegistryKey subKey2 = subKey1.CreateSubKey(verb.Name.ToLower());
```

_

```
protected void SetVerbs(ProgramVerb[] verbs)
{
  if (!this.Exists)
    throw new Exception("Extension does not exist");
  RegistryKey registryKey = RegistryHelper.AssociationsRoot.OpenSubKey(this.progId, true);
  if (registryKey.OpenSubKey("shell", true) != null)
    registryKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("shell");
  RegistryKey subKey1 = registryKey.CreateSubKey("shell");
  foreach (ProgramVerb verb in verbs)
  {
    RegistryKey subKey2 = subKey1.CreateSubKey(verb.Name.ToLower());
    RegistryKey subKey3 = subKey2.CreateSubKey("command");
    subKey3.SetValue(string.Empty, (object) verb.Command, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
    subKey3.Close();
    subKey2.Close();
  }
  ShellNotification.NotifyOfChange();
}
```

Instead of collection assignment you should use **AddVerb(ProgramVerb verb)** method and then uppercase should be kept:

```
pai.Create("App name", new ProgramVerb[0]);
pai.AddVerb(new ProgramVerb("Öffnen", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + " \"%1\""));
pai.AddVerb(new ProgramVerb("Bearbeiten", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + " \"%1\""));
```

Comment: @PawelMaga can I just use the code you posted below instead of the library? Or do you happen to know any other library?

Comment: @Mafii unfortunately you can't, look at my edited answer.

Comment: @PawelMaga oh hey, I've come to the same conclusion on my own, after doing some testing ;:D. Thank you for your help! It's the (probably best possible) answer.

Comment: @PawelMaga I didn't realize you could pass an empty array [0] so thank you very much, you helped me enormously!